# Why the auto complete drop-down list not shown

Tags: angular

My code resides [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2znam?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

I want to set up an autocomplete for the division field.

I refer the following web page:

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

However, it does not work.
I have added some console.log to show the status inside the _filter function.

Under the current environment, I found that when I typing in division field, 
there is no message display in the console.

When I do the following changes:

1. comment line 49, uncomment line 48
2. comment line 68 - 72, uncomment line 73 to 77

Although there are some messages display in the console when I typing in division field,
the drop-down list does not show.

Why the autocomplete not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your app.component.html at line no. 18:

```
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let division of filteredDivisionList |async" [value]="division">
          {{division}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
```

The name `filteredDivisionList`  mentioned in `*ngFor="let division of filteredDivisionList |async"` should match with the name of the variable `filteredDivisionList`  in the component.